# Attaching eBPF to KPROBE?

Tags: linux, bpf, ebpf

I wrote a simple program to attach to `execve` system call with a kprobe, but I am unable to see the relevant output.

Here is my one.c (BPF program):

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <bpf/bpf.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "bpf_load.h"
#include "bpf_util.h"
#include "libbpf.h"

#define SEC(NAME) __attribute__((section(NAME), used))

SEC("kprobe/execve")
int bpf_prog1(struct pt_regs *ctx)
{
        char m[]="hello world";
        bpf_trace_printk(m,sizeof(m));
        
        return 0;
}

char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
```

bpf_load.c (user space loader):

```c
#include "bpf_load.h"
#include <stdio.h>

#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (load_bpf_file("one.o")) {
        printf("%s", bpf_log_buf);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the Makefile:

```
CLANG = clang

EXECABLE = monitor-exec

BPFCODE = one

BPFTOOLS = /kernel-src/samples/bpf
BPFLOADER = $(BPFTOOLS)/bpf_load.c

INCLUDE += -I/kernel-src/samples/bpf
INCLUDE += -I/kernel-src/tools/lib

CCINCLUDE += -I/kernel-src/tools/testing/selftests/bpf
CCINCLUDE += -I/kernel-src/tools/lib/bpf
CCINCLUDE += ${INCLUDE}

LOADINCLUDE += -I/kernel-src/tools/include
LOADINCLUDE += -I/kernel-src/tools/perf
LOADINCLUDE += ${INCLUDE}
LIBRARY_PATH = -L/usr/local/lib64
BPFSO = -lbpf

.PHONY: clean bpfload build

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.so $(EXECABLE)

build: ${BPFCODE.c} ${BPFLOADER}
    $(CLANG) -O2 -DHAVE_ATTR_TEST=0 -target bpf -c $(BPFCODE:=.c) $(CCINCLUDE) -o ${BPFCODE:=.o}

bpfload: build
    clang -o $(EXECABLE) -DHAVE_ATTR_TEST=0  -lelf $(LOADINCLUDE) $(LIBRARY_PATH) $(BPFSO) \
        $(BPFLOADER) loader.c

$(EXECABLE): bpfload

.DEFAULT_GOAL := $(EXECABLE)
```

As of now I don't get any errors from the Makefile.

I am getting the following output when I execute `./monitor-exec`

```
invalid relo for insn[6].code 0x85
bpf_load_program() err=22
last insn is not an exit or jmp
processed 0 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 0 peak_states 0 mark_read 0
last insn is not an exit or jmp
processed 0 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 0 peak_states 0 mark_read 0
```

I am unable to understand what I am doing wrong. I am just attaching a kprobe and that should print `hello world` when that system call occurs.

Comment: Where does your program pick the definition for `bpf_trace_printk()` from? It looks like it does not know where to find it when libbpf attempts to perform relocation on your object file.

Comment: So what should i do? i am new to it..so as of my understanding ```bpf_trace_printk()``` definition is not in my program , am i correct?

Comment: I'm not sure because it could be in one of the files you include. But you can try adding it manually, in your BPF program file: `static int (*bpf_trace_printk)(const char *fmt, int fmt_size, ...) = (void *) BPF_FUNC_trace_printk;` (this will declare the function based on the `BPF_FUNC_trace_printk` enum member defined in linux/bpf.h, included from bpf/bpf.h I think).

Comment: okay it worked thanks....and i had one more problem ```failed to create kprobe 'execve' error 'No such file or directory' ```, , how to know the all systemcalls types that suppourt after ```kprobe/``` or anyother like uprobe,tracepoint...

Comment: Nearly all kernel functions can be traced (provided they were not inlined at compilation). You might want to check what symbols are available with something like `sudo cat /proc/kallsyms|grep execve`. Although for system calls we usually recommend using tracepoints rather than kprobes, because they are more stable (between kernel versions). In your case, there's a tracepoint called `sys_enter_execve` that you could use.

Comment: Thank you so much...upto now what i you have said really helped me...

Comment: One more doubt...How to make it listen live..so that for every system call that i have for kprobe it print's ```Hello World```. As of now when i execute ```./monitor-exec``` it's just coming out with out printing anything...suggest me the changes i need to do...i will try writing the  code for it..

Comment: Once loaded in the kernel it does nothing at first, you still need to attach your program to the hook. You should look at the `bpf_program__attach_kprobe()` (or tracepoint equivalent) in libbpf (check tools/lib/bpf/libbpf.h). I'd also suggest moving to libbpf for loading the program in the first place, because 1) it is more efficient and more feature-complete than `bpf_load.h` and 2) it will make it easier to compile your program outside of the kernel repository in the future if you simply need libbpf (and not random kernel headers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your eBPF program:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <bpf/bpf.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "bpf_load.h"
#include "bpf_util.h"
#include "libbpf.h"

#define SEC(NAME) __attribute__((section(NAME), used))

SEC("kprobe/execve")
int bpf_prog1(struct pt_regs *ctx)
{
        char m[]="hello world";
        bpf_trace_printk(m,sizeof(m));
        
        return 0;
}
```

You use `bpf_trace_printk()` correctly (although you might want to add a `\n` at the end of your message or your output will be messy), but it turns out none of the files you include contains the definition for this helper.

`bpf_trace_printk()` is compiled as part of the kernel and won't ever be compiled into your BPF object file. When trying to load your program, the function `load_bpf_file()` does a relocation step where it places the *number* associated to `bpf_trace_printk()` (in user API) in the relevant instruction of the eBPF bytecode.

But it needs to find this number somewhere. It is defined in header `linux/bpf.h` (pulled from several of your includes) as `FN(trace_printk)` (some macro magic going on), resulting *de facto* in a `#define BPF_FUNC_trace_prink 6`. But you need to tell your loading function that it corresponds to the `bpf_trace_prink()` you're calling!

Two solutions:

- Manually declare it:

  ```c
  static int (*bpf_trace_printk)(const char *fmt, int fmt_size, ...) =
          (void *) BPF_FUNC_trace_printk;
  ```
- Or add a header that contains it, e.g. tools/lib/bpf/bpf_helpers.h in kernel repo. In your case:

  ```c
  #include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
  ```

  (Note that this header is [generated](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/tools/lib/bpf/Makefile?h=v5.7#n185) when compiling libbpf, it is not present in the repository by default.)